# Qual a vantagem de se usar CHAR ao invés de VARCHAR?

Tags: sql

Qual a vantagem de se usar `CHAR` ao invés de `VARCHAR` em banco de dados já que as vantagens de `VARCHAR` excedem as de `CHAR` (se é que tem?). Existe diferença de tempo de definição de tamanho de campo já que `VARCHAR` comporta uma string de tamanho variável (até o seu limite estabelecido pelo criador da coluna)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Para começar, depende sempre do SGBD.Em teoria:

O VARCHAR é usado para guardar strings de tamanho variável e usa alocação dinámica de memória.

O CHAR tem tamanho fixo e tem alocação estática de memória.

Normalmente, se o teu conteúdo é de tamanho fixo (ou muito semelhante) então o uso de CHAR trás melhor performance. Quando o tamanho difere muito então é melhor usar o VARCHAR.

Varia conforme a implementação, mas normalmente o VARCHAR usa um ou dois bytes de memória adicionais (para tamanho ou para marcar o final dos dados) em relação ao tamanho total dos dados.

Por exemplo, para guardar a palavra "Batata"

- CHAR(6) = 6 bytes, sem overhead
- VARCHAR(10) = 8 bytes usados ( 2 de overhead)
- CHAR(10) = 10 bytes usados (4 bytes de overhead)

Em termos de performance temos duas coisas a considerar:

Com o CHAR, e uma vez que o tamanho com que defines o campo é exactamente aquele que obtens no final, o processamento das strings é mais simples uma vez que o tamanho dos dados é completamente previsível.

Com o VARCHAR, o processamente é um pouco diferente. Por exemplo, quando defines uma coluna com o tipo VARCHAR(10) na realidade o SGBD aloca dinamicamente até 11 caracters (10 + 1 para guardar o tamanho dos dados). O processamente das strings deverá sempre ter que contemplar alguma forma de validação do tamanho dos dados.

Esta diferença torna-se mais aparente quando pensamos em dois aspectos: 1) Armazenamento de milhões ou biliões de registos e 2) indexar colunas CHAR ou VARCHAR.

1). É obvio que o VARCHAR tem vantagem porque pode em teoria produzir registos mais compactos (de menor tamanho) e consequentemente, menos espaço em disco ocupado.

2). Uma vez que o CHAR requer menor manipulação dos dados devido ao tamanho fixo pode ser normalmente até 20% mais rápido a efectuar um lookup no index em comparação com o mesmo campo em VARCHAR. (Isto é válido para MySQL de acordo com o livro MySQL Database Design and Tuning)

3). Uma outra coisa a ter em consideração tem a ver com a fragmentação. Por vezes uma tabela, com ID PK VARCHAR pode ficar fragmentada devido divisão de páginas nas colunas VARCHAR. Por vezes definir a coluna como CHAR pode resover esse problema.

Uma nota final, e peço desculpa pela multiplas edições, mas o browser (IE7) está constamente a crashar.

Isto tudo que escrevi depende do SGBD e uma vez que, os SGBD melhoram constantemente, este tipo de generalização poderá acabar por, no futuro, tornar-se apenas um mito. Não há nada como testar a tua implementação e usar o conhecimento de experiências passadas para fazer escolher a melhor opção.

Comment: Estas informações são válidas até hoje? Quero muito usar campos diferentes para armazenamento de dados, e seria muito legal saber que eles ainda continuam oferecendo características diferentes!

Comment: @WesleyRedfield Sim, continuam sendo válidas.