# Qual os tipos de dados existentes em MySQL para armazenar textos e numeros inteiros?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, estrutura-de-dados, tipagem

O atributo que quero armazenar é referente a uma turma, o código dessa turma deve conter números inteiros e letras, sendo que é um atributo chave primária. Exemplo de valor que quero armazenar: SI3P39

Comment: Você pode manter o atributo id como chave primeira, e adicionar uma coluna do tipo `char` com o atributo `unique`, (caso seja um valor unico) e indexa-lo.

Comment: Sua dúvida não é relacionada ao código que você vai usar? Porque pedir para listar tudo oq ue existe é considerada uma pergunta ampla. Aqui fazemos perguntas específicas, e pareceu que o que queria era sobre o seu problema específico do código. Saber todos os tipos que existe não ajuda seu problema específico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se esse código da turma tem um tamanho específico, ou seja, sempre terá 6 caracteres, pode usar o tipo `CHAR`, se for de tamanho variável, ou seja, pode ter 4, 6, 8 ou N caracteres, então use `VARCHAR`

Em ambos os casos não deve definir a chave primaŕia como `AUTO_INCREMENT`, então quado adicionar uma linha você deve passar a chave primária explicitamente

Veja a [diferença entre `CHAR` e `VARCHAR`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61191/)

Outra opção é usar um inteiro auto incrementado, como é feito na maioria dos casos, e definir o campo turma como `UNIQUE`, assim não irá repetir. Caso tente gerará um erro

Answer (score 2):

Isto parece ser o caso de usar um `CHAR` porque [é uma descrição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101) e com tamanho fixo. Posso estar enganado quanto a saber se é de tamanho fixo, neste caso mudaria para um `VARCHAR`, mas duvido, inclusive este tipo não é candidato ideal para chave primária, embora funcione.

Mesmo que fosse só números, se ainda fosse uma descrição provavelmente ainda seria `CHAR`, tipos numéricos existem para guardar quantidades, para fazer cálculos. Note que não tem números inteiros neste código tem textos com algarismo, número inteiro implica em que vá haver matemática nisto.

Só pense bem se vai mesmo usar uma isto como chave primária, já vi muito caso que parecia ser uma boa ideia usar uma [chave natural](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277091/101), mas com o tempo se descobriu que ela precisaria mudar e aí foi um parto arrumar todo o banco de dados e nem deu para resolver sobre referências externas. Uma chave substituta resolve isto. Pense bem sobre o problema concreto. Nem vou entrar no mérito que este código pode nem ser o ideal para o processo da empresa, também já vi muito erro com códigos dentro desse padrão, mas isso não é problema da tecnologia.

Para pergunta feita não faz sentido saber uma lista de todos os tipos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -1):

As principais considerações sobre os tipos de dados.

**Tipos de dados em strings**

Strings são cadeias de caracteres. No MySQL, uma string pode ter qualquer conteúdo, desde texto simples a dados binários – tais como imagens e arquivos. Cadeias de caracteres podem ser comparadas e ser objeto de buscas.

[**CHAR**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html) — uma cadeia de caracteres (string), de tamanho fixo e não-binária;
    - Colunas do tipo CHAR(n) possuem tamanho fixo preestabelecido onde ‘n’ será igual ao total de bytes de armazenamento que a coluna irá ocupar.

[**VARCHAR**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html) — uma string de tamanho variável e não-binária;
- Colunas do tipo VARCHAR(n) ocupam 1 byte por caractere informado no registro.

[**BINARY**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html) — uma string binária de tamanho fixo;

[**VARBINARY**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html) — uma string binária de tamanho variável;
- VARBINARY é ligado a 255 bytes no MySQL 5.0.2 e abaixo, para 65kB em 5.0.3 e acima.

[**BLOB**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html) — um BLOB (Binary Large OBject – OBjeto Grande Binário) pequeno;
- Uma coluna de objeto grande binário com um comprimento máximo de 65535 (2 ^ 16 - 1) caracteres.

**TINYBLOB** — um BLOB muito pequeno;
- Uma coluna de objeto grande binário com um comprimento máximo de 255 (2 ^ 8 - 1) caracteres.

**MEDIUMBLOB** — um BLOB de tamanho médio;
- Uma coluna de objeto grande binário com um comprimento máximo de 16777215 (2 ^ 24 - 1) caracteres.

**LONGBLOB** — um BLOB grande;
- Uma coluna de objeto grande binário com um tamanho máximo de 4294967295 (2 ^ 32 - 1) caracteres.

**TINYTEXT** — uma string não-binária e de tamanho bem reduzido;
- até 255 bytes, sobrecarga de 1 byte

**TEXT** — uma string não-binária e pequena;
- até 64 Kb, 2 bytes de sobrecarga

**MEDIUMTEXT** — uma string de tamanho comum e não-binária;
- até 16 Mb, sobrecarga de 3 bytes

**LONGTEXT** — uma string não-binária de tamanho grande;
- até 4 Gb, 4 bytes de sobrecarga

**ENUM** — de acordo com o manual do MySQL, é uma string, com um valor que precisa ser selecionado de uma lista predefinida na criação da tabela;
- Um valor ENUM deve ser um dos listados na definição da coluna, ou seu equivalente numérico interno. O valor não pode ser o valor do erro (ou seja, 0 ou a string vazia). Para uma coluna definida como ENUM ('a', 'b', 'c'), valores como '', 'd' ou 'ax' são inválidos e são rejeitados.

**SET** — é um objeto que pode ter zero ou mais valores – cada um dos quais precisa ser escolhido de uma lista de valores predeterminados quando da criação da tabela.
- Um valor SET deve ser a string vazia ou um valor que consiste apenas nos valores listados na definição da coluna separada por vírgulas. Para uma coluna definida como SET ('a', 'b', 'c'), valores como 'd' ou 'a, b, c, d' são inválidos e são rejeitados.

**Tipos de dados numéricos no MySQL**

O MySQL tem todos os tipos numéricos possíveis, o que inclui exatos, aproximados, inteiros, de ponto fixo, ponto flutuante etc. A lista, abaixo, mostra um resumo dos tipos de dados possíveis no MySQL:

```
TINYINT — número inteiro muito pequeno (tiny);
SMALLINT — número inteiro pequeno;
MEDIUMINT — número inteiro de tamanho médio;
INT — número inteiro de tamanho comum;
BIGINT — número inteiro de tamanho grande;
DECIMAL — número decimal, de ponto fixo;
FLOAT — número de ponto flutuante de precisão simples (32 bits);
DOUBLE — número de ponto flutuante de precisão dupla (64 bits);
BIT — um campo de um bit.
```

Aqui segue um link para cálculo de string em byte: https://lingojam.com/ByteCounter

Tipos de datas você pode conferir mais no site oficial: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html