# Qual a problemática de se usar [n]varchar(max)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, modelagem, tipagem

Por que a prática de usar `[n]varchar(max)` pode ocasionar problemas?

Nos meus *scripts* sempre que não sei realmente qual sera a *length* de uma *string* e para prevenir problemas, eu tenho usado `nvarchar(max)`.

Há alguns dias meu supervisor de estagio estava revisando meus *scripts* e disse para eu mudar alguns `nvarchar(max)` para `nvarchar (8000)`, por exemplo. E ele citou rapidamente que eu deveria evitar declarar tudo como `max`.

Qual motivo devo evitar essa prática? Existe alguma relação com eficácia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

E você não perguntou pra ele o motivo? Deveria, se ele afirmou ele tem que fundamentar. A não ser que ele não sabia, que ele leu em algum lugar e saiu repetindo como um papagaio. Qualquer coisa sem fundamento deve ser ignorado, por isso está fazendo em certo em perguntar.

Você deve usar, a princípio, o que for mais semântico. Você quer por um limite? Colocar 8000 é um número aceitável como limite? Ou outro número é melhor, quem sabe menor? Se quer sem limite, por que faria isto?

Como otimização pode considerar o detalhe de implementação da ferramenta que está usando. Hoje, e por muito tempo, o SQL usa formas diferentes quando a coluna `VARCHAR` tem até 8000 caracteres ou pode ter mais que isto. Com esse limite o texto será gravado como parte da linha, e quando pode passar disso o texto é gravado de forma separada em outras páginas do DB, e ele faz uma espécie de *join* implícito transparente para você, mas que tem um custo extra de leitura. Costuma ter vantagem para casos assim.

Nem sempre manter textos grandes junto com a linha normal pode ser uma otimização, é difícil afirmar isso, mas se a escolha do SQL Server é sempre separar o texto quando ele pode ter mais de 8000 caracteres (eu não posso afirmar que ele faça isso sempre) e você sabe que a maioria dos textos serão pequenos, então realmente limitar em 8000 pode ser uma boa otimização porque ele lê tudo direto sempre precisar recorrer a uma leitura extra de outra página, na maioria das situações.

Pra maioria dos casos essa otimização é boba, mas se tiver volumes grandes e certos padrões então pode compensar. Tem que medir. Mas antes olhar a semântica desejada.

Ressaltando que isso vale para o SQL Server apenas, e para as versões até esta data, nada garante que será sempre assim, embora seja provável, afinal tem alguma documentação não oficial sobre isso, então teria que ser muito importante para mudar.

Pode ter algumas implicações extras, como eu disse é detalhe de implementação.

De forma geral é um bom conselho, ainda mais agora que sabe o motivo e pode tomar uma decisão melhor em cada caso. Tem a ver com eficiência, eficácia é outra coisa que é mais complicado analisar se é, ainda mais sem contexto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigada @Maniero, entendi sua explicaçao. Quando meu supervisou citou rapidamente, juntamente ele deu uma breve explicaçao, a qual nao entendi porque trabalho em outro idioma e as vezes nao fica claro para mim o que ele fala. Me falta vocabulario no outro idioma. Entao eu tento entender a ideia do que ele esta dizendo e depois pesquisar o que ele estava tentando me passar. E sim, o script que fiz e que meu supervisor revisou ia tratar uma gama enorme de dados e ficou rodando por mais de 5 horas.
Obrigada mais uma vez.

Comment: E mudando isso trouxe ganho mensurável?

Comment: Nao sei dizer, pois o script so rodou completo depois que as variaveis ja estavam mudadas para varchar(8000) e agora nao tenho mais autorizaçao de roda-lo novamente afim de fazer tal teste e sanar minha curiosidade.

Comment: É uma pena, ficou no chute se isso foi efetivo (que é diferente de eficiência e eficaz) ou não com relação à dúvida.

Comment: Sim, é uma pena.
E na pergunta, pensei eficiencia e escrevi eficacia. Perdao!

Answer (score 2):

Vou tentar explicar da melhor forma possível:

**Inicialmente em relação a diferença:**

- **char:** corresponde a um tipo de dado de tamanho fixo, utilizado para armezanar valores que possuem tamanho bem definido(CPF, Telefone...). Se o tamanho é fixo logo quando se declara `char(12)` e você armazena apenas uma letra, então será armazenado mais 11 espaços em branco.
- **varchar:** corresponde a um tipo de dado de tamanho variável, utilizado para valores que não se tem definido o tamanho(nomes de pessoas, URL's...). Se você define varchar(12) e armazena apenas um caractere será salvo apenas este caractere.

  O tipo de dados VARCHAR e CHAR armazenam os dados no padrão ASCII e utilizam 1 byte ou 8 bits para representar um caractere.
  O tamanho máximo de é de 8.000 bytes.
- **nchar:** Igual ao char mas armazena dados no padrão Unicode utilizando a representação de 1 byte para cada caractere usando assim uma representação de 16 bits.
- **nvarchar:** Quer dizer, *VARiable-length CHARacter string*, armazenam os dados em Unicode e utilizam 2 bytes ou 16 bits para representar um caractere. Logo se você utiliza nvarchar(12) será alocados 24 bytes para esse dado.

**Sobre a capacidade de armazenamento:**

O varchar pode ser tão grande quanto a pagina de dados do banco.

Uma página de dados é o local onde são armazenados os seus dados, ou seja, quando eu crio uma tabela e insiro registros nessa tabela esses registros são alocados em páginas de dados no SQL Server.

O tamanho de uma página de tabela é 8196 bytes, e uma linha em uma tabela não pode ser superior a 8.060 caracteres. Este, por sua vez, limita o tamanho máximo de um VARCHAR para 8.000 bytes.

A utilização de **MAX** indica que esses tipos de dados(nchar ou nvarchar) podem armazenar um valor superior aos seus respectivos limites: 8000 e 4000 bytes. O varchar(max) armazena 2GB e fica alocado em um lugar diferente da página de dados.

***VARCHAR (MAX):** indica que o tamanho máximo de armazenamento para o tipo de dados VARCHAR é 2^31 bytes ( 2 GB)*

***NVARCHAR (MAX):** indica que o tamanho máximo de armazenamento para NVARCHAR o tipo de dados é 2^31 bytes ( 2 GB)*

**Resumo geral:**

*nvarchar()* é o dobro de espaço de um *varchar()*, e *nvarchar(max)* é o dobro de espaço de um *nvarchar()*, se você sempre utiliza o **max**, você pode acabar perdendo performance do banco, pela necessidade de sempre ter de alocar uma quantidade desnecessária de armazenamento.

**Existem outras perguntas aqui no SOpt sobre isso:**

[Qual a vantagem de se usar CHAR ao invés de VARCHAR?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61191/qual-a-vantagem-de-se-usar-char-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de-varchar?rq=1)

Comment: Você leu a pergunta? Acha que isso responde o que foi perguntado?

Comment: desculpa, acabei clicando em responder sem antes terminar de responder de fato

Comment: Obrigada @CedricS.
Sua resposta tambéem me ajudou a compreender melhor o impacto da pratica que eu estava fazendo.

Comment: Não entendi bem isso: "se você sempre utiliza o max, você pode acabar perdendo performance do banco, pela necessidade de sempre ter de alocar uma quantidade desnecessária de armazenamento." - mas se é variável, por qual razão ele alocaria algo desnecessário? Ou você quis dizer que SE o dado for maior que 8000, isso ocorrerá? E ai eu pergunto, nesse caso é melhor armazenar o que passou, ou perder a informação?

Comment: "mas se é variável, por qual razão ele alocaria algo desnecessário?" - No momento de criar a instância do novo dado no campo, o espaço de armazenamento é alocado na memória para receber a entrada do valor. Caso eu esteja falando algo de errado espero que me corrijam mas foi como aprendi